# Papa Rudin theorem $1.39$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

There is the theorem:
Suppose $f:X\to [0,\infty ]$ is measurable, $E\in\mathfrak{M}$, and $\displaystyle \int \limits _Ef\,d\mu =0$. Then $f=0$ almost everywhere on $E$.

There is the proof:
If $A_n=\left \{x\in E:f(x)>\dfrac{1}{n}\right \}$, $n=1,2,3,\ldots$, then$$\frac{1}{n}\mu (A_n)\leq \int \limits _{A_n}f\,d\mu \leq \int \limits _Ef\,d\mu =0,$$so that $\mu (A_n)=0$. Since $\displaystyle \{x\in E:f(x)>0\}=\bigcup \limits _{n=1}^\infty A_n$, the theorem follows.

I don't understand how  we get this inequality $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n}\mu(A_n)\leq \int \limits _{A_n}f\,d\mu$ .

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use an intermediate step of $$\frac1n\mu(A_n) = \int_{A_n} \frac1n\,d\mu \leq \int_{A_n}f\,d\mu$$ Do you see it now?

Comment: You have ${1 \over n}1_{A_n}(x) \le f(x)$ for all $x$. Now integrate both sides.