# Rudin's RCA: $2.14$ theorem step $X$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

This is the definition which we need in the proof:
[image]

source : [Rudin proof of theorem 2.14 RCA inequality explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3245231/rudin-proof-of-theorem-2-14-rca-inequality-explanation)

> **Proof.**
> Clearly, it is enough to prove this for real $f$.
> Also, it is enough to prove the *inequality*
> \begin{equation}
>   \tag{16}
>        \Lambda f
>   \leq \int_X f \,\mathrm{d}\mu
> \end{equation}
> for every real $f \in C_c(X)$.
> For once $(16)$ is established, the linearity of $\Lambda$ shows that
> $$
>        -\Lambda f
>   =    \Lambda(-f)
>   \leq \int_X (-f) \,\mathrm{d}\mu
>   =    - \int_X f \,\mathrm{d}\mu,
> $$
> which, together with $(16)$ shows that equality holds in $(16)$.

> Let $K$ be the support of the real $f \in C_c(X)$, let $[a,b]$ be an interval which contains the range of $f$ (note the Corollary to Theorem 2.10), choose $\epsilon > 0$, and choose $y_i$, for $i = 0, 1, \dotsc, n$, so that $y_i - y_{i-1} < \epsilon$ and
> \begin{equation}
>   \tag{17}
>   y_0 < a < y_1 < \dotsb < y_n = b.
> \end{equation}
> Put
> \begin{equation}
>   \tag{18}
>     E_i
>   = \{ x : y_{i-1} < f(x) \leq y_i \} \cap K
>   \qquad
>   (i = 1, \dotsc, n)
> \end{equation}
> Since $f$ is continuous, $f$ is Borel measurable, and the sets $E_i$ are therefore disjoint Borel sets whose union is $K$.
> There are open sets $V_i \supset E_i$ such that
> \begin{equation}
>   \tag{19}
>     \mu(V_i)
>   < \mu(E_i) + \frac{\epsilon}{n}
>   \qquad
>   (i = 1, \dotsc, n)
> \end{equation}
> and such that $f(x) < y_i + \epsilon$ for all $x \in V_i$.
> By Theorem 2.13, there are functions $h_i \prec V_i$ such that $\sum h_i = 1$ on $K$.
> Hence $f = \sum h_i f$, and Step II shows that
> $$
>        \mu(K)
>   \leq \Lambda\left( \sum h_i \right)
>   =    \sum \Lambda h_i.
> $$
> Since $h_i f \leq (y_i + \epsilon) h_i$, and since $y_i - \epsilon < f(x)$ on $E_i$, we have
> \begin{align*}
>         \Lambda f
>   &=    \sum_{i=1}^n \Lambda(h_i f)
>    \leq \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i + \epsilon) \Lambda h_i \\
>   &=    \sum_{i=1}^n (|a| + y_i + \epsilon) \Lambda h_i
>         - |a| \sum_{i=1}^n \Lambda h_i \\
>  (1) &\leq \sum_{i=1}^n (|a| + y_i + \epsilon)[ \mu(E_i) + \epsilon/n ]       
>         - |a| \mu(K) \\
>   &=    \sum_{i=1}^n (y _i - \epsilon) \mu(E_i)
>         + 2 \epsilon \mu(K)
>         + \frac{\epsilon}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (|a| + y_i + \epsilon) \\        
>  (2) &\leq \int_X f \,\mathrm{d}\mu
>         + \epsilon[ 2\mu(K) + |a| + b + \epsilon ].
> \end{align*}

I couldn't understand why is $\sum_{i=1}^n (|a| + y_i + \epsilon)[ \mu(E_i) + \epsilon/n ]       
        - |a| \mu(K) \\$
equal of $\sum_{i=1}^n (y _i - \epsilon) \mu(E_i)
        + 2 \epsilon \mu(K)
        + \frac{\epsilon}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (|a| + y_i + \epsilon) \\  $.

I also don't understand that how does the fact that $y_i - \epsilon$ $\lt$ $f(x)$ on $E_i$ implies that $\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\epsilon)\mu(E_i)$ $\leq$ $\int_X f d\mu$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you see that $$\int_X f\,d\mu = \sum_{i=1}^n \int_{E_i} f\, d\mu?$$ If so, the answer to your second question is the same as in math.stackexchange.com/q/4528258

Comment: @BrianMoehring i can see but we have integral sign there

Comment: Just so linked questions works correctly, here's that link again: [https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4528258](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4528258)

Comment: @BrianMoehring thx.  
If you can please answer on the 1 st question too

Comment: Honestly, I don't know a good way to convey the answer to your first question in a static medium like this.  If I were writing an answer in which that step is required, I would only note that it uses $\sum_i\mu(E_i)=\mu(K)$ for the reader, but otherwise I'd just let the equation speak for itself (aside from the identity I've noted, it's just pushing symbols around distributive properties and the fact $1 = 2-1$)

Comment: @BrianMoehring thank you again